# Where has the Search tab in Google Chrome Developer tools gone?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

The Search tab used to be found in tab next to the tabs Console, Emulation and Rendering, but it seems to have gone missing.

This search tab was really good for text searching that searched in any loaded resource.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've moved the global Search to a place that we think will be more discoverable in the long run, the new main menu:

[image: search in main menu]

Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: When you use that, the old tab pops up where it used to be. Why not have the tab there in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I found this [shortcut page](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/shortcuts) that suggests using `Ctrl+Shift+F` (Win) or `Cmd+Opt+F` (Mac) after opening the **Developer Tools** to reveal the tab **Text search across all sources**.

A bit sad that it isn't shown from start when the Developer Tool are opened.

[image]